# Upload Images via multipart form to Hippo CMS

Tags: hippocms

I use Hippo mostly as headless CMS to provide assets for a Unity client. In the process the client generates some images which I want to load into Hippo. My first approach was to create a custom REST API which consumes a multipart/form-data request with the image files. I do have 2 questions:
1. Is this the correct approach for my problem?
2. If so: In my REST Endpoint I receive the Files but I have no clue how to add them as image to Hippo. Can anyone give me a hint here?

best regards
Jacob

Answer (score 0):

I'd be a bit worried about securing that rest endpoint but other than that I don't see a problem. As for adding an image, you basically create a node with the image type and put the image as a binary property. You should look at the source for the image gallery processor and the nodes in the console for inspiration.